# MDM Zinc - Make window resizeable

Tags: mdm-zinc

I'm using MDM Zinc 3. I'd like to create a desktop application for Windows with it. How to make the final projector window resizable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Window Type to "Standard Resizeable" in the Zinc 3.0 Interface (In the Window Properties Pane)

Answer (score 1):

Also when providing content in scalable native window please make sure that - if you manage Flash stage scaling in your implementation - in Zinc Builder "Window Properties" section on the right "Scale Movie While Resizing" is unchecked.
Familiarize with that settings as it manage how content is scaled in native window - you could left it checked (which is default) or uncheck it and manage content scaling using Stage object features,

kind regards,
Peter Blazejewicz